# MYSQL group by for separate id

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

So here is the structure and query: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de7ec8/4

And this is the result:

```
+-------------+--------+
| id_requests | status |
+-------------+--------+
|           1 |      0 |
|           1 |      0 |
|           1 |      1 |
|           2 |      1 |
+-------------+--------+
4 rows in set
```

and im looking for this result:

```
+-------------+--------+
| id_requests | status |
+-------------+--------+
|           1 |      0 |
|           1 |      1 |
|           2 |      1 |
+-------------+--------+
3 rows in set
```

I want to group by status but for each id_requests, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you  are looking for selecting distinct rows  for this use distinct  clause

```
SELECT distinct a.id_requests, b.status 
FROM `admin_availability_requests` a
```